# jqGrid inline edit problem

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I wanna use jqGrid inline(row) edit, but how can I put "Edit", "Cancel", "Save"and "Delete" buttons besides every row.

There's a example in officaill website about how to put "Edit", "Cancel" and "Save" buttons for inline(row) edit, I tried to put delete button, but it doesn't work. How can I do it? thx

Comment: Did you manage to figure out what puts the buttons there inline?
Is it JavaScript-code? And where in the JavaScript does this happen?

Comment: As Natrium suggested, it helps when you post a question if you show an example of the code you've tried that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
     ....
     colNames:[...,'Actions'],
     ....    
     colModel:[ .... , { 
        name: "actions", 
        classes:'jg_actions', 
        formatter: "actions", 
        editable: false, 
        sortable: false, 
        resizable: false, 
        fixed: true, 
        width:60, 
        formatoptions: {keys: true, delbutton:true}}
 ...
```

This will put inline edit buttons at the end of each row

Comment: where can i format these buttons? I have row spans on my rows and so I don't want a button for each row. i want the rowspans to applied instead. Any idea where that can be applied?

Answer (score 0):

please go to http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html# check every link specially Live Data Manipulation and custom edit link ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the code that didn't work?

The function to delete a row is [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#delgridrow) - it has grid in the name, unlike editRow, saveRow, restoreRow.